# WPF 2つ以上のXAMLでデータを共通で使いたい｡

Tags: wpf, xaml

C#, WPFでアプリケーション開発を行っているのですが､2つのページで同じデータを共通で表示したいです｡
バインディングを使うと思われるのですが､どうもうまくいきません…

例えば
UserControl1.xamlにTreeView､
UserControl2.xamlにUserControl1.xamlのTreeViewで選択したitem名が表示されるTextBox｡
という構成にしたい場合

どのように各xamlにバインド定義を書くべきかご教授ください｡
※情報が少ないかもしれません｡｡すみません｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各ユーザーコントロールに内部状態を公開するための[**依存関係プロパティ**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx)を定義するのが良いと思います。

具体的な手順としては

1. 各ユーザーコントロールのコードビハンドで`propdp`コードスニペットを実行し、依存関係プロパティを定義する。
2. ユーザーコントロールのXAML内部の`TreeView`や`TextBox`で`RelativeSource`を用いて定義したプロパティにバインドする。
3. ユーザーコントロールを含むビューでプロパティ同士が関連付けられるようにバインドする。

のようになります。

例えば単に`TreeView`もしくは`TextBox`を含むユーザーコントロールがあり、それぞれに`SelectedText`プロパティを定義する場合を考えます。依存関係プロパティは`propdp`からプロパティ型、プロパティ名、オーナー型、初期値の4か所を書き換えて以下のようになります。

```
public string SelectedText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

このプロパティに`TextBox`をバインドするためのXAMLは

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="UserControl2"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hoge">
    <TextBox
        Text="{Binding SelectedText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UserControl2}}" />
</UserControl>
```

となります。

一方`TreeView`の選択項目はバインド不可ですのでコードビハンドを使用して

```
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    // SelectedItemの型は実装に合わせて変える
    SelectedText = (((TreeView)sender).SelectedItem as TreeViewItem).Header?.ToString();
}
```

のように`TreeView.SelectedItemChanged`で設定を行います。

各コントロールがこのように実装されていれば、両者を使うビューでは

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <local:UserControl1
        x:Name="uc1" />
    <local:UserControl2
        Grid.Row="1"
        SelectedText="{Binding ElementName=uc1, Path=SelectedText}" />
</Grid>
```

のように直接コントロールのプロパティにバインドしたり、あるいは両プロパティを他の同一プロパティにバインドすることで値を同期させることが出来ます。

Comment: さっそくの回答ありがとうございます｡ ほぼコピペですが…私の環境で私が求める結果となりました｡　ちなみに共有する値がstringではなく､intもしくは自作クラスの場合は上記サンプルソース内でtypeofで指定いる型を変更すればよろしいでしょうか｡

Comment: @KazukiSaito プロパティの型を変える場合は、通常のプロパティ(CLRプロパティ)の型指定と`DependencyProperty.Register`の第二引数および既定値(`PropertyMetadata`コンストラクターの引数)の三か所を変更しなければなりません。